# ReactJS Toggling Props Length

Tags: reactjs

I have a show/hide functionality that I am building out for a component and I am wondering how I can toggle the length of a string from 5 characters to its full length and back based on a button click and the previous state. I have the button click and a boolean indicating a true/false state, but I am not sure how I can switch between the 5 character limit and full length. I can only get the expanded text and not the original state.

Based on a state boolean (`showFullText`) I thought of this solution:

```
if (this.state.showFullText == false){
            partialText = this.props.discovery.slice(0, this.state.characterLimit);
        } else {
            partialText = this.props.discovery;
        }
```

but it is not working within the context of this code. No error message.

```
import React from 'react';

//Annotation Card - Body
export default class Body extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { showFullText: false, characterLimit: 10 };
        this.showHideFullText = this.showHideFullText.bind(this);
    }

    showHideFullText(){
        console.log(this.state.showFullText);
        this.setState({
            showFullText: !this.state.showFullText,
            characterLimit: this.props.discovery.length,
            expandButtonText: "Show Less"
        });
    }

    render() {

        var partialText;
        if (this.state.showFullText == false){
            partialText = this.props.discovery.slice(0, this.state.characterLimit);
        } else {
            partialText = this.props.discovery;
        }

        var textExpandButton;
        if(this.props.discovery.length >= this.state.characterLimit) { 
            textExpandButton = <TextExpandButton showHide={this.showHideFullText} showFullText={this.state.showFullText} />;
        } else { 
            return this.props.discovery; 
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <p>{partialText}</p>
                {textExpandButton}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

//Annotation Card - Body - Text Expand Link
export const TextExpandButton = props => {
    var buttonText;
    if(props.showFullText === true){
        buttonText = "Show Less";
    } else {
        buttonText = "Show More...";
    }
    return <a href="#" onClick={props.showHide}>{buttonText}</a>
}
```

Comment: Can you place a minimally verifiable code at sandbox?

Comment: You have the min length set to 10 by default -- is that the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The approach to use a toggled boolean in state is a great one because of its simplicity.

In `Body.showHideFullText`, `characterLimit` is being set to the length of `discovery` and `this.props.discovery.slice(0, this.state.characterLimit)` really is `this.props.discovery.slice(0, discovery.length)`.

`characterLimit` should possibly be a write once value (set to `5` as the initial state of `Body` component). I'll suggest making this a property of `Body` and setting its default value to `5`. There is no reason to keep it in state with your present requirements for the component.

In `Body.showHideFullText`, only toggle the boolean value for `showFullText`

```
showHideFullText(){
  this.setState(
    prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      showFullText: !prevState.showFullText,
    })
  );
}
```

I don't find it necessary to store `expandButtonText` in the component state because its value can be decided from the value for `showFullText`.

> **Update:** Code for affected components ([Run on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-eh43hh))

**Body.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import TextExpandButton from './TextExpandButton';

class Body extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { showFullText: false };
    this.toggleFullTextDisplay = this.toggleFullTextDisplay.bind(this);
  }

  toggleFullTextDisplay() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      showFullText: !prevState.showFullText,
    }));
  }

  render() {
    const { discovery, characterLimit } = this.props;
    const { showFullText } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <p>{showFullText ? discovery : discovery.slice(0, characterLimit)}</p>
        {discovery.length >= characterLimit && <TextExpandButton showFullText={showFullText} toggleFullTextDisplay={this.toggleFullTextDisplay} />}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Body.defaultProps = {
  characterLimit: 5
};

Body.propTypes = {
  characterLimit: PropTypes.number,
  discovery: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default Body;
```

**TextExpandButton.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const TextExpandButton = props => {
  const { showFullText, toggleFullTextDisplay } = props;
  const buttonText = showFullText ? "Show Less" : "Show More...";
  return (
    <a href="#"
       onClick={props.toggleFullTextDisplay}
    >
      {buttonText}
    </a>
  );
}

TextExpandButton.propTypes = {
  showFullText: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  toggleFullTextDisplay: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default TextExpandButton;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm trying to follow along, but got lost at a few points. What I have gathered is that there is no need to have more than a boolean (`showFullText`) as the method to change both the button text and the discovery length from "5" to the full length. Where I am lost is where you suggest "making this a property of Body with default set to 5. Do you mind add the suggested code to your answer to help clear up my confusion?